# Google Maps API V3: KML Layer not showing?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a KML file that I copy/paste together form a fusiontable which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-73.992177,40.743465,0.0 -74.008242,40.752352,0.0 -74.006533,40.756112,0.0 -73.983973,40.748934,0.0 -73.987733,40.744149,0.0 -73.992177,40.743465,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-73.973035,40.689458,0.0 -73.989784,40.683305,0.0 -74.008242,40.686381,0.0 -73.978846,40.705181,0.0 -73.977479,40.698003,0.0 -73.973035,40.689458,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
(...)
</Document>
</kml>
```

As far as I understand drawing these on the map is as easy as

```
var zipoverlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer('zips.kml');
zipoverlay.setMap(map);
```

But apparently this does nothing. Is it not as magical as I thought?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Dr.Molle we figured this out. Here's what I did wrong:

1. The KML file needs to be accessible from outside my own machine. Host it somewhere else in order for maps to be able to grab it
2. The structure of the KML file needs to be like this:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-73.992177,40.743465,0.0 -74.008242,40.752352,0.0 -74.006533,40.756112,0.0 -73.983973,40.748934,0.0 -73.987733,40.744149,0.0 -73.992177,40.743465,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>
<Placemark><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-73.973035,40.689458,0.0 -73.989784,40.683305,0.0 -74.008242,40.686381,0.0 -73.978846,40.705181,0.0 -73.977479,40.698003,0.0 -73.973035,40.689458,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Document></kml>
```

Comment: To anybody else that finds this there are a couple mistakes in the above example, and also some fallacies.  It is not necessary to remove whitespace in the manner suggested.  Also the example above has close tags instead of open tags above at the top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

A `<Polygon/>` has to be a child of either `<Placemark/>` or `<MultiGeometry/>`, but not of `<Document/>`

Comment: Hmm.. Very odd. I've tried this with the simplest of KML files (first example here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons) and that still didn't work using the same code to add it. It DOES however do something if I call the code from another server (ie https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml). i tried loading it via localhost:8888, but I'm beginning to think it must live externally?

Comment: Ok, so externally this is working. But why am I only getting one of the polygons defined here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18072730/zips.kml

Comment: the `<Document/>` is missing there

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was having HTTP auth enabled on my server, which was preventing google from requesting the KML file.  I guess it is not done client side.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of issue (kml layer not displaying) because the url (or maybejust the file name) was too long.
With a shorter url it was working.